# NODEMON not launching although node is updated and NPM is initialized

Tags: node.js

Since 3 days ago my nodemon wasn't able to launch from every single project folder. When trying to launch it, it displays this:

```
$ nodemon app.js
C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found
```

Note that I have have updated my node to the latest version and npm was initalized. This really is blocking my developement so any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

nodemon install globally and try

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

Comment: installing nodemon globally was one of my first attempts but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: uninstall the nodemon and Re-install globally and project